# Java: The constructor ... refers to the missing type SQLException

Tags: java, maven

I came around a strange error while running a Jira plugin I was writing.

The plugin compiles and runs and I see no sense for not being able to find `SQLException` type, which is explicitly importent in the plugin with:

```
 import java.sql.SQLException;
```

And, as far as I know it's part of Java runtime, so I do not need to include any other jars.

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2012-11-25 16:00:36,739 http-2990-1 ERROR      [atlassian.plugin.servlet.DefaultServletModuleManager] Unable to create servlet
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference$InitializationException: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   The constructor TestRun(String) refers to the missing type SQLException
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference.getInterruptibly(LazyReference.java:152)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:115)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.DefaultServletModuleManager.getServlet(DefaultServletModuleManager.java:344)
```

And here is the info regarding how Jira started, which seems fine for me:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] ___ Java Class Paths _______________________
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]      sun.boot.class.path                           : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                                                      /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                                                      /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                                                      /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                                                      /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                                                      /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                                                      /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                                                      /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/JObjC.jar:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                                                      /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/classes
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]      java.library.path                             : /Users/sorins/Library/Java/Extensions:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                                                      /Library/Java/Extensions:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                                                      /Network/Library/Java/Extensions:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                                                      /System/Library/Java/Extensions:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                                                      /usr/lib/java:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                                                      .
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]      java.endorsed.dirs                            : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/endorsed
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]      java.ext.dirs                                 : /Users/sorins/Library/Java/Extensions:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                                                      /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                                                      /Library/Java/Extensions:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                                                      /Network/Library/Java/Extensions:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                                                      /System/Library/Java/Extensions:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                                                      /usr/lib/java
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]      java.class.path                               : /Users/sorins/dev/jira/jira-libs.hg/plugins/testrun/target/container/tomcat6x/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/bin/bootstrap.jar:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                                                      /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
```

Comment: I would guess that you're missing a JAR file.

Comment: It seems more likely that there are two definitions of SQLException on the classpath. When this occurs, one definition is loaded and the other definition is referenced, you get this crazy "cannot find class" error even though it's clearly there.

Comment: I doubt there is another `SQLException` class than `java.sql.SQLException` as I already did an extensive search on .java and jar fiels and found only this one. Also this one is part of the `rt.jar` which as you can see it's already loaded.

Comment: I am wondering if this can have anything to do with the fact that I'm using Java 1.7 under OS X 10.8